# Three js converting an equirectangular panorama to cubemap format using NEXT JS

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to convert an equirectangular panorama image to cubemap format using NEXT JS. The scene get rendered but the background doesn't apply. And I get no errors!

```js
import { useLoader, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

const Background = (props) => {
    const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, "/autoshop.jpg");

    const { gl } = useThree();

    const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(
        texture.image.height
    ).fromEquirectangularTexture(gl, texture);

    console.log("formatted", formatted);

    return <primitive attach="background" object={formatted} />;
};

export default Background;
```

And I call it wrapped by Suspense:

```js
<Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Background />
</Suspense>
```

Comment: Does the cubemap, generated from this tool (https://jaxry.github.io/panorama-to-cubemap/) work in your app? Can you also add the image you're using to your question?

Comment: Yes, the cubemap generated works fine! But I couldn't upload the image as it's bigger than the allowed size. Thank you.

Comment: For the consistency, I'll be using this one: https://www.flickr.com/photos/jonragnarsson/2294472375/

Comment: @MohammadTbeishat That image is exactly the one that's used [in this Three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic). Just look at the source code (The `< >` icon in the corner) and take a look at how they're doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Marquizzo comment. I found out that I can do the same thing in another way. By replacing:

```js
const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(
    texture.image.height
).fromEquirectangularTexture(gl, texture);
```

by:

```js
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
```

Comment: note: gl is the renderer

Comment: "Hi @Mohammad, I am trying to render a panorama image using 'pannellum-react,' which is working fine on larger screens like laptops and tablets. However, some mobile devices are unable to view the image. The error message states: 'This panorama is too big for your device! It's 8192px wide, but your device only supports images up to 4096px wide. Try another device. (If you're the author, try scaling down the image).' I searched for a solution and found that generating a cube map image and using it in Pannellum might work." Did you tried the same here? if so, need your help on this

Comment: Hi @MONEYMSN ,
Quoting from pannellum-react documentation: "Currently there are some problem with React V18".. Therefore, I recommend using React v17 if possible. Alternatively, you can try using a cube map for your panorama, although I haven't personally worked with Pannellum before. Best of luck!